# Can't change post author with blogdown

Tags: r, post, author, blogdown

I have successfully used the `blogdown` R package for a few months now for the blog of my team at work, until the moment I was not the only author anymore.

At that point I realized that the author's name specified in the blog post was not really taken into account. Instead, it was read by default from the `config.toml`.

The relevant part of my `config.toml` looks like this:

```
[Author]
name = "Darth Vader"
profile = "https://linkedin.com/in/darthvader/"
```

And the top part of the specific blog post is structured like follows:

```
---
title: A new hope
author: Luke Skywalker
date: '2017-10-10'
---
```

However, it is Darth Vader that invariably appears as the post author, regardless of what the `author:` field contains. If I leave the `config.toml`'s field empty, then no name at all appears once the .Rmd is rendered.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is probably more dependent on hugo than blogdown, and there may be information in the hugo docs. Especially check the docs for your chosen theme.

Comment: It seems you are correct. This bug was referenced in the homepage of the Hugo theme in question (https://github.com/jbub/ghostwriter).

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it; sorry there isn't a solution!

Comment: I contacted the theme maintainer and the bug is now gone! https://github.com/jbub/ghostwriter/commit/d40349f7692bd3a0b2e99798dba6d6b87c10d12c

Comment: Fantastic. You've gotta love open source. If you can I'd write that up as an answer and accept it so others can see the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from the discussion under the main post:

I contacted the theme maintainer and the bug is now gone! https://github.com/jbub/ghostwriter/commit/d40349f7692bd3a0b2e99798dba6d6b87c10d12c